# join two arrays as one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have searched and the solution I have seen is `arr1.push(...arr2)`, but when i try it and console log the result i only get a number returned which I guess is the length or something.

My first arr looks like this

```
Array [
  
  Object {
    "first_name": "ann",
    "id": "23440",
    "last_name": "",
    "phone_number": "+51556078",
  },
  Object {
    "first_name": "steve",
    "id": "15692",
    "last_name": "",
    "phone_number": "+15953333",
  },
  Object {
    "first_name": "John",
    "id": "13111",
    "last_name": "",
    "phone_number": "+43879009",
  },
]
```

second array

```
Array [
  Object {
    
    "first_name": "King",
    "gender": "",
    "id": 3,
    "identification": "",
    "last_name": "gerald",
    "phone_number": "+65060738",
   
    
  },
  Object {
    
    "first_name": "Jonny",
    "gender": "",
    "id": 4,
    "identification": "",
    "last_name": "Bro",
    "nin": "",
    "phone_number": "+51556078",
    
    
  },
]
```

what i want is all the objects in the first array to be appended to the second array so i can display one list of `first_name` and `phone_number`

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a _[mcve]_.

Comment: *"arr1.push(...arr2), but when i try it and console log the result i only get a number returned which I guess is the length or something.*" `.push()` returns the new length but still adds the items to the array you've called it on. So `arr1.push(...arr2)` will add all the items in `arr2` into `arr1`. You should be logging `arr1` to see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try with the `concat()` function, It would return a new array `result` that contains `array1` and `array2` values:

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6];

let result = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(result);
```

More info at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp.

- As @Boaz said, you can also use the `push()` method, but It will change the original array. This approach would return the length of the modified array:

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6];

let array1_length = array1.push(...array2);
console.log(array1_length);  //print new array1 length
console.log(array1);   //print new array
```

Comment: This is by far the better option, as it does not change any of the arrays involved and returns the resulting new array. It might be well to add a note about how `push` mutates the original array and returns its new length.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value) returns the new length of the array. `console.log(array1.push(...array2))` will return the `(array1.length + arra2.length)`

```js
let a = [1,2,3]
let b = [5,6]
console.log(a.push(4))
console.log(a)
console.log(a.push(...b))
console.log(a)
```

You can log the array variable to check that your array is well modified.
If you want to make use of the spread operator you can always do:
`let c = [...a,...b]`